# How to use the back button correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with back button in my app.
I mean I am using react-router-last-location to know my last page:

```js
const backUrl = this.props.lastLocation ? this.props.lastLocation.pathname : MAIN_PAGE;
```

The problem is:

e.g. From main page "/" I clicked to "cards" and my route changed to "/cards", then I clicked to any card and my route changed to "/card/64531", then I clicked to information tab and my route changed to "/card/64531/info".
If I try to use back button from last page ("/card/64531/info") my route will be changed to "/card/64531". Then if I try to use back button my route will be changed to "/card/64531/info", and this will be change in a circle. How to fix it?

Comment: use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the top of my head, I would implement a LIFO (Last In Frist Out) stack, where you push every url change to that stack and then take out the last elements from it on every back button press.

Just make sure you are not adding to the stack urls that are triggered by the back button.